# Could not add entry to cache fileSnapshots.bin

Tags: android, caching, android-studio

I copied my project folder for wiping my hard drive and now, trying to import in Android Studio I get this error on buildgradle

```
Error:Could not add entry '2095793483774087535' to cache fileSnapshots.bin (/home/ivan/Forotek/.gradle/1.10/taskArtifacts/fileSnapshots.bin).
```

> Corrupted IndexBlock 6198 found in cache '/home/ivan/Forotek/.gradle/1.10/taskArtifacts/fileSnapshots.bin'.

I tried importing in Windows, Mac & Linux, I get the same error always

Answer (score 30):

I just had this happen to me.  Deleted the ".gradle" directory and then did a "Sync Project with Gradle Files".  Once I did that, I was able to successfully build the project again.

Comment: remove .gradle and gradle --stop

Answer (score 17):

open terminal in android studio and type this command and rebuild your project it will 100% work

**Note: -this command will only work with mac or linux machines**

```
rm -R .gradle
```

In case of windows you can find similar command to delete the directory
forcefully and it works

Answer (score 14):

Same issue here for build of Android apk using Android Studio 1.0.2.

```
I have removed the file fileSnapshots.bin
```

Afterwards I did clean + rebuild from the menu.

Answer (score 3):

### Just go and `delete` the `fileSnapshots.bin` file located under:

```
/{YourProjectLocation}/.gradle/{YourGradleVersion}/taskArtifacts/fileSnapshots.bin
```

#### E.g. for me it was here:

```
~/Projects/MyProjectName/.gradle/2.14.1/taskArtifacts/fileSnapshots.bin
```

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me too, the following command fixed it:

```
gradlew -C rebuild
```

Answer (score 0):

change in your Project build.gradle version on 1.5
Here **build.gradle** file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options 
common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
 repositories {
    jcenter()
 }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
  }
}
allprojects {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
}
```

and in **gradle-wrapper.properties** be sure, that you use gradle of version 2.8

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.8-all.zip
```

Answer (score -1):

I had to do the following to completely remove the gradle cache:

1. Clean local git repo to sync with remote: a) `git clean -f -x -d -n` for dry run, to make sure `.gradle/` folder will be removed b) `git clean -f -x -d` to actually run it
2. Restart Android Studio (with Invalidate Cache)
3. Rebuild project